# can't acess my checkbox with JQuery

Tags: jquery

i encounter troubles to acess an input of type chekcbox with JQuery here is my html code :

```
<th class="bill"  width="19%" scope="col">

      <input type="checkbox" name="sup'+i+'" class="bill" value="'+i+'"/>

</th>
```

here you see that my input is inside a  tag that have a class "bill", now i want to capture the event on my checkbox and simply write a message.

```
$('.bill input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
     console.log("it works");
})
```

But nothing appears in the console !! it seems that there is something wrong with my event listener.

Comment: Nadjib if you move the TH into `<table><thead>` then it works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `click` event and determine whether or not it is checked when the event fires

```
$('input.bill[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
   if( $(this).is(':checked') )
      console.log("it works");
});
```

```js
$('input.bill[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
   //optional logic to determine if checkbox was checked
   if( $(this).is(':checked') )
      console.log("it works");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<th class="bill" width="19%" scope="col">
  <input type="checkbox" name="sup'+i+'" class="bill" value="'+i+'" />
</th>
```

Although you can also use the `change` event as others have pointed out.

```
$('input.bill[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
   if( $(this).is(':checked') )
      console.log("it works");
});
```

Main thing to take away from this is that your selector is incorrect, you need to select on:

1. The specific input element first - `input`
2. Then specify the class - `.bill`
3. followed by any other attributes associated with it `[type=checkbox]`

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong selector.

```js
$("input.bill[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
     console.log("it works");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<th class="bill"  width="19%" scope="col">

      <input type="checkbox" name="sup'+i+'" class="bill" value="'+i+'"/>

</th>
```

Also this works

```
$("input.bill:checkbox").change(function() {
     console.log("it works");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    console.log("it works");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put an id to the checkbox element

```
<th class="bill"  width="19%" scope="col">

  <input type="checkbox" id="billSup" name="sup'+i+'" class="bill" value="'+i+'"/>
```

Now you will get console

```
$('#billSup').on('change', function(){
   console.log("it works");
});
```